Which battery clamp is positive?
Car is a Hyundai coupe 2l 2006 but I’m also asking about cars in general.
Usually if you are facing the car the fuse box is on your right and the engine is on your left, you positioning yourself in front of the battery.
Is it correct that the fuse box side on clamp is always/mostly the negative and the terminal on your left is usually/mostly the positive?
I've previously destroyed relays due to getting them wrong and recently I removed a battery then realised I forgot to note which clamp was positive and which was negative.
In such case where the clamps are not marked or even incorrectly have a red cover etc, what is the best way to figure out which clamp is positive?  Perhaps you should follow both clamp cables and what component will it be connected to?

Several clues exist.

For any "modern" car later than the 1960's, the engine is wired "negative ground"   Vintage vehicles may be wired with "positive ground" but both are possible. The wording tells you which battery terminal is connected through the chassis/frame of the car, so the other terminal needs a wire of its own and this will generally be fused.In your case, I'd expect positive to go to fuses and to the starter, and negative to be straight to the chassis/engine block.

Many batteries have terminals of different sizes, so the clamps will have different internal bore widths.   Put the wider clamp on the fatter terminal post.   (assumes you have the old battery to compare or that you bought the right replacement battery)

Wires will take a "Set" - that means they develop a bit of a memory and want to rest/hang in their original position.   You can use that to gauge which one went where, though this also assumes you bought a battery with the same terminal configuration

Read the labels on the battery wires.   If yours are unlabelled, then grab a sharpie and label them.  Even red and black insulation tape works because red is positive and black is negative.


Also, sometimes older vehicles get rewired from positive to negative earth.  Look for signs/labels.

It is amazing how true #3 is, even to wiring other than the battery. Got my butt out of a wringer more than once trying to figure out which wire might go where.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yeah - it doesn't help if the battery was removed years ago and everything's just been left to slump over years.   But sometimes you have to take the clues where they are.
